# Access every member of base template class

Tags: c++

When you use template inheritence, you have to explicitly specify what members of base template class you intend to use:

```
template <typename T>
class base 
{
protected:
    int x;
};

template <typename T>
class derived : public base<T> 
{
public:
    int f() { return x; }
protected:
    using base<T>::x;
};
```

What if base template has a lot of members? Can I avoid writing `using` declaration for each member and  specify that I want every member of base template?

Comment: Just qualify every access with `this->`. We usually don't like to do that, but it will resolve all the dependent names as you use them, without bringing them in with a using declaration. `this->` may not be much shorter than a fully qualified `base<T>::`, but in other cases it sure can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no such mechanism in the language.

Comment: It's to do with two-phase lookup, no?

Answer (score 1):

For that reason, i usually introduce a member named `inherited`.

e.g.

```
using inherited = base<T>;
```

Then to access the members of the base class, the code would look like:

```
int f() { return inherited::x; }
```

This approach has the advantage, that you can easily differentiate which member you are referring to (if required, using `this` only for own members).